# I can't add a new line when writing a file in Python

Tags: python, file-writing

I am making a data file in python:

```
use = input('')
if use == '2':
  taken = []
  names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']
  file_name1 = random.choice(names)
  file_name2 = random.choice(names)
  file_name3 = random.choice(names)
  file_name4 = random.choice(names)
  file_name = (file_name1 + file_name2 + file_name3 + file_name4)
  if file_name in taken:
    print('An error occurred, please try again!')
  else:
    taken.append(file_name)
    file = open('logs.txt', 'w')
    file.write(file_name + '\n')
    file.close()
    print('Done')
```

Every time I run this I want to add a newline but in fact it always modifys the first line, why?

Comment: What behavior do you want? `if file_name in taken:` this condition is always `False`, then `else` branch is executed which write 'logs.txt` file.

Comment: i need it so write on a new line in the file but instead it keeps on modifying the file

Comment: Do you mean to add one line every time you run this script?

Comment: Yes,  i need to write the object then ski pa line and write the next object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is appending to the file, instead of writing (truncating the file if it already exists):

```py
    # ...

    else:
        taken.append(file_name)
        file = open('logs.txt', 'a+')  # 'a+' mode instead of 'w' mode
        file.write(file_name + '\n')
        file.close()
    # ...
```

Refer to [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Answer (score 0):

Use open(file, mode) with the pathname of a file as file and mode as "w" to open the file for writing. Call file. write(data) with data as a string containing the newline character "\n" as its last character to write a line to file and to create a new line for the next written string.